# Resume partial dnf package downloads

Tags: linux, fedora, download, package-management, dnf

I have a slow, metered and unstable connection.

I use Fedora 24 and its default package manager is `dnf`. If downloads fail amidst an install, it will skip packages that have been already download ***in its entirety***.

I'm trying to install `xonotic` and one of its packages has 865 MB:

```
 darkplaces          x86_64    20150825-5.fc24  fedora    2.5 M
 opengl-games-utils  noarch    0.2-8.fc24       fedora    12 k
 xonotic             x86_64    0.8.1-5.fc24     fedora    2.6 M
 xonotic-data        noarch    0.8.1-2.fc24     fedora    865 M
```

If the download fails, even if it's at 99%, `dnf` will restart the `xonotic-data` download at 0%

```
[SKIPPED] xonotic-0.8.1-5.fc24.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                         
[SKIPPED] darkplaces-20150825-5.fc24.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                   
[SKIPPED] opengl-games-utils-0.2-8.fc24.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded   
xonotic-data-0.8.1-2.fc24.noarch.rpm               1% [-
```

Is there any way to have `dnf` just download the missing bits?

I have tried `keepcache` on the conf file but it has no effect.

Comment: [Also posted on Unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385689/resume-partial-dnf-package-downloads). [Please don't do that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1051548), downloads *are* actually resumed, but the UI does not reflect this well. If that's not happening, it's probably worth filing another bug.

In the meantime, if that's not working for you, I suggest downloading the problematic file using a program that you know works, and then installing it locally (like, `dnf install ~/Downloads/xonotic*.rpm`).